# How to listen for data in named pipe in Java/Kotlin in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, kotlin, named-pipes

I want to listen for a named pipe on Linux (and only Linux) using Kotlin or Java. Currently I do the following:

```
val reader = File(PIPE_NAME).bufferedReader()
while (true) {
  reader.readLine()?.let { string ->
  // Next actions
}
```

This approach works, however the downside is that if nothing is available at the moment, `readLine` will return null, so the loop will consume the CPU.

Adding `sleep` is not an option as it's critical to get data ASAP.

So, the question is — is it possible to somehow read lines from a named pipe only when they're available and block otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood properly, the problem starts when other side closes pipe, we may overcome that by opening pipe in rw mode:

```java
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(PIPE_NAME, "rw")) {
    String str;
    while ((str = raf.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

in that case you will never get EOF since pipe is always open for write, thus the while loop never exits, however I do believe that is exactly what you want to achieve.

Another options is to reopen pipe after EOF, i.e.:

```java
while (true) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PIPE_NAME))) {
        String str;
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```